# Articles for filename extensions

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-articles

When writing file extentions, (mainly on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)) I write `.txt` or `.avi`.

Should I write an `.avi` file or a `.avi` file?

Because if I was to say it outloud, I would say `a dot avi` - but I am not sure whether this is right.

Comment: There is also the special case of files such as ".emacs", which have only an extension, for which you would usually not skip the dot when pronouncing the name.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on the user and the context.

If you are referring to the extension itself, such as:

```
Then save the file with a .html extension
```

Then, since you're referring to the ".html" extension, which needs a DOT to differentiate between a specific extension and an ambiguous file type, use "a dot html". In this case, you CANNOT call it "a html extension" since that doesn't define what the extension actually is.

However, if you're referring to the file itself, such as so:

```
There should be an AVI file there.
```

Use the form "an AVI" here.

Again, if you refer to files with the extension, such as

```
There should be <article> .avi file.
```

Then, use the word dot as well. Ignoring the fullstop when writing file types (not extensions) would be how I'd solve this. Truly a matter of preference, understandable either way, but slightly different.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was the same as LightMikeE (ie I said "...a dot html" in my head), but then read his first example as "an html extension". My brain skipped the . in .html because it didn't 'see' it as ending a sentence, so it somehow didn't mentally 'count'.

So I'd say follow normal rules - if the extension starts with a vowel, use 'an', whether you include the preceding dot or not.

Comment: I agree with this, but pedantically note that html doesn't start with a vowel, although the name of its first letter does.

Answer (score 1):

There's two good answers here already, but I don't think there's a hard and fast rule about this as it's such a common problem. I would say that it doesn't really matter which you use as long as there's no possibility of confusion. In the UK some land is designated for its nature value. These sites are known variously, in both spoken and written usage, as:

> 1. A Site of Special Scientific Interest
> 2. A Triple S.I. [ess eye]
> 3. An SSSI (ess ess ess eye]

As far as I'm aware there have been no objections, arguments or confusion about the 'correct' way.

So I would say, if these files are normally referred to as *dot avi* files then go with **a .avi**.

Comment: I agree, though there are prescriptive guidance to follow, I would not read the dot aloud. a avi file or an avi file- should not raise any eyebrows.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dnaaz, but would modify his response to say "follow normal rules - if the extension starts with a vowel *or vowel sound*, use 'an,' whether you include the preceding dot or not."

I also agree with LightMikeE's response except for the first example he gives, which (following Dnaaz's advice as modified above) should read "an .html."